# What is the object found by the bed?

Tags: planetarium

In Planetarium by Rebecca Zlotowski an object was found near her bed:

[image]

What is that object?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a slightly higher quality screenshot. It appears to be a mouse in a copper tube. I've no idea why it's there or what it's doing though